# How to do pattern matching with alias type

Tags: python, mypy

This simple example works

```
from linesParser import get_ProcessCell
from typing import List,Tuple,Union

ti=Tuple[int,int]
ua=Union[int,ti]

a=(3,3)
match a:
    case (x,y):
        print("A")
    case _:
        print("B")
```

But if I change the definition of ti in something more complicated like an union of different tuples

```
ti=Union[Tuple[int,int],Tuple[int,int,int]]
ua=Union[int,ti]
a=(3,3)
match a:
    case (x,y) | (x2,y2,z2):
        print("A")
    case _:
        print("B")
```

mypy myfile.py returns

> tobedeteled.py:9: error: Alternative patterns bind different names

I've tried that too

```
from linesParser import get_ProcessCell
from typing import List,Tuple,Union

ti=Union[Tuple[int,int],Tuple[int,int,int]]
ua=Union[int,ti]

a=(3,3)
match a:
    case isinstance(a,ti):
        print("A")
    case _:
        print("B")
```

> error: Expected type in class pattern; found "isinstance"

I would prefer a solution like the the last because if I change the definition of ti again I don't want to change the code in the case statement.

**sequel**

After reading this [website](https://buddy.works/tutorials/structural-pattern-matching-In-python) I tried this

```
from linesParser import get_ProcessCell
from typing import List,Tuple,Union

ti=Union[Tuple[int,int],Tuple[int,int,int]]
ua=Union[int,ti]
a=(3,3) match a:
    case ti() as ati:
        print("A")
    case _:
        print("B")
```

> error: Class pattern class must not be a type alias with type parameters  [misc]

```
from linesParser import get_ProcessCell
from typing import List,Tuple,Union

ti=Union[Tuple[int,int],Tuple[int,int,int]]
ua=Union[int,ti]
a=(3,3)
match a:
    case ti(ati):
        print("A")
    case _:
        print("B")
```

> error: Class pattern class must not be a type alias with type parameters  [misc]

**sequel 2**

I ve tried this way. mypy raise no error but it doesn't work.

```
a:ua=(1,3)
if type(a) is ti:
    print("A")
elif type(a) is int:
    print("B")
else:
    print("C")
```

C is printed...

Comment: Changing the definition of `ti` has nothing to do with the error you report.

Comment: python version ?

Comment: Type hints have nothing to do with pattern matching. The text following the `case` keyword is *just* a pattern; it's not a Python expression, even if it *looks* like one. `(x, y)`, in particular, will match *any* two-element sequence, not just a 2-tuple.

Comment: If you want to match an instance of an actual type (not a type hint), see ["Class patterns" in PEP 634](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/#class-patterns).

Comment: @tremendows 3.11

Comment: `ti` is not a type; it's an instance of `typing._GenericAlias` that can be used as a type hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there isn't a really convenient way to properly support changing ti. There probably exists some library to convert generic types to matching_patterns, I wouldn't know of any though.

Here's the solution to match your ti.

```
ti=Union[Tuple[int,int],Tuple[int,int,int]]
ua=Union[int,ti]

a: ua = Any()
match a:
    case (int(), int()) | (int(), int(), int()) as x:
        reveal_type(x) # Union[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int, int]]
        print("A")
    case _:
        print("B")
```

Quickly - why did your previous examples not work?

1. When applying a match all variable names used in any option must be bound/assigned - else we wouldn't know which variables exist...

```
ti=Union[Tuple[int,int],Tuple[int,int,int]]
ua=Union[int,ti]
a=(3,3)
match a:
   case (x,y) | (x2,y2,z2):
       # does x even exist? what if the tuple had 3 elements - in that case
       # x doesn't exist but x2 does - if the tuple had two elements x2 wouldn't exist... in each option we must assign all variables to not have possibly non-existing variables. 
       print("A")
   case _:
       print("B")
```

2. Isinstance doesn't work a match-case isn't a cascade of ifs. Isisinstance would work if you did:

```
if isinstance(a, ti):
    print("A")
else:
    print("B")
```

3. 'Class pattern class must not be a type alias with type parameters?' - Why is that so? Due to [type erasure](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#instantiating-generic-classes-and-type-erasure) - which more or less means that generic types (when you use `[...]` on a type) disappear at runtime - the usage of generic types is disallowed in a `case`.
4. Sequel 2 - As said, types aren't stored on your instances. The type of `a` in the sequal2 example is just `<class 'tuple'>`

Answer (score 2):

`(x, y)` is an example of a *sequence pattern*. It is not a tuple; it's a pattern that will match *any* sequence (lists, tuples, etc) with exactly two values, and bind the first value to `x` and the second value to `y`:

```
match (1,2):
    case (x, y):
        print(x + y)  # Outputs 3
```

`ti` is not a type: it is an instance of `typing._GenericAlias` that can be used as a type hint.

`(x, y) | (x2, y2, z2)` is a syntax error in Python, (not just something `mypy` cannot handle) because if it were to match, you wouldn't know if `x` and `y` were defined, or if `x2`, `y2`, and `z2` were defined. No sequence would result in *both* sets of variables being defined.

If you want to match a tuple with 2 *or more* items, you can use a star pattern to capture values 3+ (if they exist).

```
match (1, 2):
    case (x, y, *rest):
        assert x == 1
        assert y == 2
        assert rest == []
```

If you want to limit the number of optional values in the match, you'll need to use a guard:

```
match (1, 2, 3, 4, 5):
    case (x, y, *rest) if len(rest) <= 1:
        # Matches 2 or 3 elements
        print("shouldn't see this")
        print(x, y, rest)
    case (x, y, z, *rest):
        # Matches 4 or more, because the previous
        # case would match 3-element sequences
        print("Found 4 or more items")
        assert x == 1
        assert y == 2
        assert z == 3
        assert rest == [4, 5]
```